# Heroku custom url works as redirect instead of alias

Tags: url, heroku

I added domains to my heroku project:

```
 $ heroku domains
=== diveintoworld Heroku Domain
diveintoworld.herokuapp.com
=== diveintoworld Custom Domains
Domain Name            DNS Target
─────────────────────  ───────────────────────────
diveintoworld.com      diveintoworld.herokuapp.com
www.diveintoworld.com  diveintoworld.herokuapp.com

$ host www.diveintoworld.com
www.diveintoworld.com is an alias for diveintoworld.herokuapp.com.
```

Created `CNAME` record in my domain settings:

```
www.diveintoworld.com. CNAME diveintoworld.herokuapp.com.
```

And set up web redirect from `diveintoworld.com` to `www.diveintoworld.com`.

Seems like nothing was missed but all these things work like redirect.
`www.diveintoworld.com->diveintoworld.herokuapp.com`

But I need to make my site available under `www.diveintoworld.com`. (When user see my site he should see this url rather than heroku url in his address line.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run

```
curl -s -I www.diveintoworld.com
```

It returns a 301. Which means that your app might be doing the unexpected redirect.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: https://diveintoworld.herokuapp.com/
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 70
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 05:34:24 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

`X-Powered-By: Express` is from the `express.js` framework which I'm assuming is the one you used to develop your website. Do you have somewhere in your app code a redirect to the heroku url? Perhaps an environment specific config that sets the app host?

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

The problem was a misconfiguration of the `HEROKU_URL` in the configuration of the app. In this case the [Ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) platform was used and the config documentation for the url is available [here](http://support.ghost.org/config/#url).

Setting `HEROKU_URL` with `http://www.diveintoworld.com`, clearing cache or trying in private tab did the trick.

Comment: As it seems related to your app code we'd need to see your routes and at least your home controller action to see if anything is triggering the 301.

Comment: @Mark here is my root script http://pastebin.com/pm4Ajvni and config.js http://pastebin.com/t7f4e1Kp

Comment: Have you tried replacing process.env.HEROKU_URL in your config hash with your custom domain name url? Just to see if this changes anything...

Comment: @Mark I changed my HEROKU_URL from https://diveintoworld.herokuapp.com to http://diveintoworld.com - blog worked as before, admin panel didn't work

Comment: @rocknow without controller code we're a bit in the dark here... If you have an app.get(*, function(){...}) somewhere please post its content. Please also post the content of your app.get("/", f(){...}). You're not giving much information...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110101/discussion-between-marc-lainez-and-rocknow).

Comment: Important to note for cloudflare users:   
Set the HEROKU_URL varible with 'http', not 'https'